# How to get a list of columns that will give me a unique record in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My intension is to write a python function that would take a pyspark DataFrame as input, and its output would be a list of columns (could be multiple lists) that gives a unique record when combined together.

So, if you take a set of values for the columns in the list, you would always get just 1 record from the DataFrame.

Example:
Input Dataframe

```
Name    Role    id
--------------------
Tony    Dev     130
Stark   Qa      131
Steve   Prod    132
Roger   Dev     133
--------------------
```

Output:

```
Name,Role
Name,id 
Name,id,Role
```

Why is the output what it is?
For any Name,Role combination I will always get just 1 record
And, for any Name, id combination I will always get just 1 record.

Comment: Shouldn't `Name, Role, id` be also in the expected result?

Comment: Hey Richard, Yeah...I missed that and edited it in. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to define a function, which will do exactly what you are asking for.

I will only show 1 possibility and it is a very naive solution. You can iterate through all the combinations of columns and check whether they form a unique entry in the table:

```
import itertools as it

def find_all_unique_columns_naive(df):
    cols = df.columns

    res = []
    for num_of_cols in range(1, len(cols) + 1):
        for comb in it.combinations(cols, num_of_cols):
            num_of_nonunique = df.groupBy(*comb).count().where("count > 1").count()

            if not num_of_nonunique:
                res.append(comb)
    return res
```

With a result for your example being:

```
[('Name',), ('id',), ('Name', 'Role'), ('Name', 'id'), ('Role', 'id'), 
 ('Name', 'Role', 'id')]
```

There is obviously a performance issue, since this function is exponentially increasing in time as the number of columns grow, i.e. `O(2^N)`. Meaning the runtime for a table with just 20 columns is already going to take quite a long time.

There are however some obvious ways to speed this up, f.e. in case you already know that column `Name` is unique, then definitely any combination which includes the already known unique combination will remain unique, hence you can already by that fact deduce that combinations `(Name, Role), (Name, id)` and `(Name, Role, id)` are unique as well and this will definitely reduce the search space quite efficiently. The worst case scenario however remains the same, i.e. in case the table has no unique combination of columns, you will have to exhaust the entire search space to make that conclusion.

As a conclusion, I'd suggest that you should think about why you want this function in the first place. There might be some specific use-cases for small tables I agree, just to save some time, but to be completely honest, this is not how one should treat a table. If a table exists, then there should be a purpose for the table to exist and a proper table design, i.e. how are the data inside the table really structured and updated. And that should be the starting point when looking for unique identifiers. Because even though you will be able to find other unique identifiers now with this method, it very well might be the case that the table design will destroy them with the next update. I'd much rather suggest to use the table's metadata and documentation, because then you can be sure that you are treating the table in the correct way as it was designed and, in case the table has a lot of columns, it is actually faster.